# GTK# resolution is wrong in windows

Tags: gtk#

I'm writing a cross platform desktop app using monodevelop, and I'm trying to use GTK. When I run it on windows, it doesn't scale correctly to the display, it is double sized. But not all the details are scaling wrong, so there are border details that display at the correct size, and the result is I get artifacts all over the form. It looks terrible. I move the code to windows, and compile it there using VS2015, and I get the same result.

Windows forms work as expected, and scale the same on both windows and linux, so I'm currently using them, but it looks so vb6...I would rather use GTK.

This happens on both an asus zenbook, and surface pro 4. I think it is because they both have high dpi screens.

How can I set GTKSharp to scale correctly in windows?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the environment variable GDK_SCALE=1. You won't get a double-sized app, but things will be in the right locations (even if they are annoyingly tiny).

This is a rather serious problem with GTK on Windows, and I hope someone can provide a better solution.

Just out of curiosity, are you working with GTK+2 or GTK+3?